# Parsing the Json in tableview using Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am new in  parsing json.I made a single view application .I got json from url using this function .

```
func parseData(){
        //created URL
        guard let requestURL = URL(string: "https://machla.bh/api-category2") else {return }

        //creating URLRequest
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)

        //setting the method to post
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //creating the post parameter by concatenating the keys and values from text field
        var postParameters = ""

        postParameters += "key=LpfyirxoNOfP8wPns4nZqTw6DQ4wY A2q6yvpKsof6gkYDTykVXSEonTO2VB HE2zRdqrvsyoyMVyRagWtKAtVuOuNs c7QW5KrgbXS8SqPZ7sIDlPEvhBWyo5 NoObAcor3GlO87nRSaFdxhKDRTiBkK 3pFsTQyffzuBdIBiM8zFra6Yh8NbbC QQaratgFFE2hzLouNEIHq88xaSqum1 C0z7g325i3hixT5oLSo5tvhpvvdTJO WohfqGSakeGz7hsAU"

        postParameters += "&path=59"

        postParameters += "&language_id=1"

        //adding the parameters to request body
        request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: .utf8)

        //creating a task to send the post request
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            guard error == nil else {
                print("error is \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data was returned by the request!")
                return
            }


            // print data from request
            let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
              print(str)
            for eachFetechedCountry in str
            {
                let eachCountry=eachFetechedCountry as! [String:Any]
                let category = eachCountry["categories"] as! String
                let product=eachCountry["products"] as! String
                self.fetchcountry.append(Country(categories: category, products: product))

            }
            self.countryTableView.reloadData()

        }

        //executing the task
        task.resume()

  }
```

I am trying to read categories and products from json using following statement in above function.These statement are not working.How to read categories and products from json?

```
 for eachFetechedCountry in str
                {
                    let eachCountry=eachFetechedCountry as! [String:Any]
                    let category = eachCountry["categories"] as! String
                    let product=eachCountry["products"] as! String
                    self.fetchcountry.append(Country(categories: category, products: product))

                }
```

For populating categories and product into table view i created a class named country

```
class Country{

    var product:String
    var category:String

    init(categories :String, products:String)
    {
        self.category=categories
        self.product=products
    }

}
```

For populating categories and product into table view i coded

```
func tableView(_ tableViewr: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = countryTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text=fetchcountry[indexPath.row].category
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text=fetchcountry[indexPath.row].product
        return cell!

    }
```

how to populate categories and product into table view ?

From this link you can download sample project for correction?https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnY3RicXpGN1FYbXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/150322/swift-json-tutorial-2

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: Questions about parsing JSON are one of the – felt – top 5 questions here on SO. Did you search: [Here are more than 2700 related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+parse+json). You missed the step to deserialize the JSON data.

Comment: `let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!; print(str) ;for eachFetechedCountry in str` NO, NO, and NO. Just print `eachFetechedCountry` in the for loop you'll see. Do instead: `if let json = JSONSerialization(...) as dictOrArrayReflectingTheStructureOfTheJSON`, then do you for loop if needed.

Comment: please explain with code statement  @ Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use feature of Swift 4 - Decodable protocol.

```
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

       guard error == nil else {
          print("error is \(error!.localizedDescription)")
          return
       }

       guard let data = data else {
          print("No data was returned by the request!")
          return
       }

       do {
          let country = try JSONDecoder().decode(Country.self, from: data)

          // do what you want here with Country array
          // ...

       } catch let error {
          // catch error and handled it here
       }

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.countryTableView.reloadData()
       }
   }

   //executing the task
   task.resume()
```

**Always update tableview in Main thread!!!**

And use those structs:

```
struct Country: Decodable{
    var categories: [Category]
}  

struct Category: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var products: [Product]
}

struct Product: Decodable {
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: How to get categories and products from json.                                         let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
              print(str)

Comment: You can get categories let categories = country.categories
For example: let firstProduct = country.categories.first?.products.first

Comment: I want to fetch data from json and fill data into table view .. do { let country = try JSONDecoder().decode(myCountry.self, from: data) let categories = country.categories.first?.name let firstProduct = country.categories.first?.products.first?.name self.fetchcountry.append(Country(categories: categories!, products: firstProduct!)) } catch let error { } ----------- i did not got categories name and products name ? the compiler doesnot read further away from (let country = try JSONDecoder().decode(myCountry.self, from: data)) tryafter try fails it get caught .

Comment: I did not got categories name and products name to append it fetchcountry array to show them table view .from this link you can down load the sample project for correction  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnWGgyY1p0SWpvQXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have wrong response from server, it return different types for a few items. You should check it. But if you want get only name of category and product - you can use those structs: 

struct MyCountry: Decodable{
    let categories: [Category]
}
struct Category: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let products: [Product]
}
struct Product: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

Comment: the compiler does not get valid value form try statement:-                                      do {
          let country = try JSONDecoder().decode(Country.self, from: data)       it simply get caught in to " catch let error {
          // catch error and handled it here
       }"...How i can make try a valid statement and get valid value ?

Comment: It's because you receive field with different data type(once String, another Bool). Change your structs and try again. I receive valid value after run your code with my changes.

Comment: please make changes of data type in to code of your answer .